# How to show the number of Group?

Tags: jasper-reports

I created a report to generate user which has a list of departments. I need to count the group but not the records within the group.

How to do it with *JasperReports*?

For example: -

```
**No: 1**
Name      : User1
Department: Depart1
            Depart2
            Depart3

**No: 2**
Name      : User2
Department: Depart1
            Depart2
            Depart3

**No: 3**
Name      : User3
Department: Depart1
            Depart2
            Depart3
```

In the above example, I need to count the count them 1, 2, 3 for 3 users. I don't want the numbering to count the records within the user, means I do not need the count to count the numbers of department for each user.

Currently, I create a group for the **User** and there is a variable automatically created "User_COUNT". I use that in my detail band but it seems counting each records in the user group.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the variable on your Group.

The sample:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="count_groups" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="7ca8f323-3cc7-4980-9222-77fb0f8f556b">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="Name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Department" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="cntUser" class="java.lang.Integer" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="userGroup">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[($V{userGroup_COUNT} == 1) ? $V{cntUser} + 1 : $V{cntUser}]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[1]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="userGroup">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{Name}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="50">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="da974bc0-323d-4169-b584-eddb4ffcfa50" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["No: " + $V{cntUser}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement uuid="57fcf335-26f2-44b4-89ad-11c1223c9539" x="0" y="30" width="100" height="20"/>
                    <textElement markup="none"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Name         :]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="16ccb7f0-eb39-403e-b7c4-1c6f35989f3d" x="100" y="30" width="100" height="20"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="4647a9aa-229e-4f5d-8d08-aca4cda1df2f" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Department}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="bc4bd9ae-6c2f-43c2-823e-1501b76ef39a" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{userGroup_COUNT} == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Department:]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The report design in *iReport* is looks like this:

[image: Report's design in iReport]

For this input data (I've used *CSV* datasource in sample):

```
Name,Department
User1,Depart1
User1,Depart2
User1,Depart3
User2,Depart2
User2,Depart3
User3,Depart1
User3,Depart4
User3,Depart4
User3,Depart4
```

The result will be (via preview in *iReport*):

[image: The result in iReport]

*Details*:
In this sample I've used variable ***cntUser*** with **Increment Type** equals to ***Group*** (for group named *userGroup*). This variable incremented (see the *variableExpression*) only for the first record in each *Group* (the check 
*`$V{userGroup_COUNT} == 1`*).

*Note:* Don't forget to sort data if you are using the *Grouping*

Comment: Yes, thank you! Spend an hour googling how to get index of each group

Comment: Hi, My report don't have detail section *group* i'm using and printing the group details in *table footer section* here i need count(Serial Number) for group details only. And i tried this $V{userGroup_COUNT} == 1 its not working for me. please suggest me how to get count for grouping.

Answer (score 0):

```
<variable name="COUNT_GROUP" class="java.lang.Integer" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="province" calculation="Count">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{COUNT_GROUP}]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[1]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

Comment: Do consider revising your answer to include small explanation of the snippet.