# How to print serial number in report only when specific column value is not null in report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a serial number column in my report where I want to display serial number when a specific column value is not null. So for that i have created a Group called `EmployeeSerialNumber` and set Group Expression as `$F{empid}` and in serial number text field properites, i have set
`new Boolean($V{EmployeeSerialNumber_COUNT}.intValue()==1)` for`Print When Expression` and for `Text Field Expression` has set `$V{REPORT_COUNT}`

But preview is coming as follows

```
SlNo.    empid       intime         outime  
1         100         9:00           1:00  
                      2:00           6:00  
3         101         9:10           1:20
```

But, I want the preview as follows :

```
SlNo.    empid       intime         outime  
1         100         9:00           1:00  
                      2:00           6:00  
2         101         9:10           1:20
```

Could anybody please help me, much appreciated

Comment: @Shan Possible duplicate: [How to calculate the number of groups](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17480184/876298)

Comment: Thanks, its working now with help of this link (How to calculate the number of groups – Alex K)