# Set order number for group in IReport

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a group in my report. Now, i want create order number for this group.

```
No    Group's name    Record
1       grp1-------------------------------
                                record1
                                record2
2       grp2------------------------------
                                record3
                                record4
```

I was created variables "STT" , but didn't run. Detail:

```
- Variable Class; java.lang.Integer

 - Calculation: Nothing

 - Reset type: None

 - Increment type: Group

 - Variable Expression:    ($V{STT} == null?0:$V{STT}) + 1

 - Initial Value Expression: new Interger(0)
```

And i set Evaluation Time: Group

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the number of groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480184/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-groups)

Answer (score 0):

- Variable Class; java.lang.Integer

  - Calculation: COUNT
  - Reset type: None
  - Increment type: Group
  - Variable Expression:    ($V{STT} == null?0:$V{STT}) + 1
  - Initial Value Expression: new Interger(0)

Comment: And i set Evaluation Time: Group